# Having trouble understanding this question propositional logic (substitution) discrete mathematics

Tags: logic, substitution

I am not understanding how to solve substitution instances, could someone please explain how it works?

3. Which of the following propositional formulas are substitution instances of the formula P → (Q → P)?

If a formula is indeed a substitution instance, give the formulas substituted for P,Q.

(i) ¬R → (R → ¬R)

(ii) ¬R → (¬R → ¬R)

(iii) ¬R → (¬R → R)

(iv) (P ∧ Q → P) → ((Q → P) → (P ∧ Q → P))

(v) ((P → P) → P) → ((P → (P → (P → P))))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) is a substitution instance of $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$ because we can obtain (i) by substituting $\neg R$ for $P$ and $R$ for $Q$.

Likewise, (ii) is a substitution instance of $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$, by substituting $\neg R$ for both $P$ and $Q$.

(iii) is, however, *not* a substitution instance of $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$.

Can you do the rest from here?

Comment: I am really struggling to understand this question, would you be able to show me how ¬R substitutes for p and R for Q for (I)? just so I can see an example please?

Comment: no worries I have figured it out, thanks so much for this help.